# Trouble with spell checking

Tags: java

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out why my program tells me some of the words are spelled correctly when they are not and vice versa 
My problem states: 
1) Determine if a word entered by the user is spelled correctly. A word is considered correct if it's found in dictionary.txt (see required output to get file).

My code thus far is

```
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Filereader {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        RandomAccessFile br = new RandomAccessFile("dictionary.txt", "r"); // it is for processing
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Scanner object for input
        String s;

        while (true) {//To run program until user enters exit
            System.out.println("Enter word to spellcheck (or exit to end)\n");

            String key = input.nextLine();
            if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) //testing wether user entered exit word
            {
                System.out.println("Ending program.....");
                System.exit(0); //for exiting from program
            } else {
                while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (s.contains(key)) //used to search word in given file
                    {
                        System.out.println(key + " spelled correctly\n");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(key + " not spelled correctly\n"); //if word is not present in file
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're creating output after comparing the entered word with ***every*** word in the dictionary, and this doesn't make sense. Instead, read the dictionary into an array list at the beginning of the program, and then check any entered word to see if it is contained in the `ArrayList<String>` using the `.contains(...)` method.

Comment: Your indentation is a mess, but I won't fix it as some reviewers don't think indentation is important!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this part of your code:

```
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (s.contains(key)) {
        System.out.println(key + " spelled correctly\n");
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println(key + " not spelled correctly\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

The `while` loop will be terminated after the **first** check because of the `if-else` statement as the `key` is either contained or not contained into `s`.

You could use a **boolean** flag instead:

```
boolean correct = false;

while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (s.contains(key)) {
        correct = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (correct) {
    System.out.println(key + " spelled correctly\n");
} else {
    System.out.println(key + " not spelled correctly\n");
}
```